# .Net 5 Azure functions Json Settings

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

Struggling to find how  set the serialiser settings in .Net 5 Azure Functions

```
static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new HostBuilder()
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
                {
                    configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
                    
             
                })
                .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((hostBuilderContext, workerApplicationBuilder) =>
                {
                    workerApplicationBuilder.UseFunctionExecutionMiddleware();
      


                })
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    
                    
                
                })
                .Build();

            return host.RunAsync();
        }
```

does anyone have an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please try the code below:

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var host = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(builder => {
               
                //use this code for json settings
                builder.Services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson(option =>
                {
                    option.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(xxx);
                });
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                
            })
            .Build();

        await host.RunAsync();
    }
```

Note that the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/5.0.5) should be installed.